# NPM Install Failing on CodeBuild while trying to pull from private Codecommit repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, npm-install, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

One of my repo's in codecommit is trying to pull from another of my codecommit repos.

Inside the first repo's package.json there is the dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
      "repo-2": "git+https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/repo-2.git#TAG"
}
```

My codebuild is throwing the error when attempting to `npm install` (codebuild is using nodejs12):

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --mirror -q https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/repo-2.git 
   /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-3d2bf4b6/.git
npm ERR! warning: templates not found in /tmp/pacote-git-template-tmp/git-clone-7cae5b66
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-26T11_58_45_260Z-debug.log
```

I've made sure to give the correct permissions in my policy:

```
      - Sid: CodeCommitRepoAccess
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - codecommit:GetRepository
          - codecommit:GitPull
          - codecommit:GetFolder
        Resource: 
          - arn:aws:codecommit:eu-west-1:*
      - Sid: CodeCommitListRepos
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - codecommit:ListRepositories
        Resource: "*"
```

And I've added in the git-credential helper in the buildspec.yaml:

```
env:
   git-credential-helper: yes
```

I'm really at a loss about why this is failing, and the error message isn't giving me any ideas of what needs fixing. Perhaps I have the missed some permissions in the policy? - but as its not a 403 error I'm not sure. I can `npm install` locally on my machine without any issues.

EDIT:
To actually be clearer, I am trying to build from repo-1, which has a dependencies on repo-2 and repo-3. Additionally, repo-2 has a dependency on repo-3 as well. I tried running `npm install` without the nested private repository (removed it from the package.json as a test) but the build still failed the same way.

UPDATE:
I added the line `git ls-remote -h -t https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/repo-2.git`to my buildspec and this correctly returns the branches/tags in repo-2, so permissions look fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer in case anyone has the same issue:

Adding in the following to my buildspec under the install phase solved the issue:

```
      - git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
      - git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

I also needed to **remove** the git-credential helper from my build spec:

```
env:
    git-credential-helper: yes
```

I think what what was causing the issue was that the `npm install` was not picking up the git-credential helper when it was set with env, but did get picked when it was set explicitly.